# Looking for an API that gives planet positions for a horoscope app

Tags: javascript, html, api, css

I'm working on an art project where I want to generate horoscopes based on the current planet positions. I want to makes these somewhat realistic, but I don't know if there is any "planet positions" API, or something for horoscopes that is free. Does anyone know of anything like this? I'm just making a basic web app in html, css, and js if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[programmableweb.com](https://www.programmableweb.com/) is the first place I stop looking for web APIs covering all sorts of subject matter.

Quick search there shows promising results under "astrology" like

> **[Cerridwen](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/cerridwen)**  Cerridwen provides planetary data that focuses on our solar system and is suitable for both astronomical and astrological
>   uses. This data includes sunrise times, phases of the moon, the
>   tropical position of the sun, etc. Cerridwen's primary data sources
>   are the Swiss Ephemeris library and its own algorithms, which
>   calculate the phases of the moon and other planetary aspects and
>   events.

and

Under "planet position" you'll find [Ephemeris](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/astro-physcom-ephemeris) -

> Ephemerides (singular: ephemeris) are tables of values that give the
>   positions of astronomical objects in the sky at a given point in time.
>   Object positions are written in terms of right ascension and
>   declination. Davy Wybiral has created the Ephemeris API as a method of
>   querying NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL) planetary ephemerides,
>   which are generally created to support spacecraft missions to other
>   planets. The Astro-Phys.com Ephemeris service can be accessed using
>   RESTful calls issued in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you! I think that Cerridwen will work out really well for my purposes!